# Python 2.7.3 Flask ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask application with this error:

```
ImportError: No module named annotaria, referer: http://ltw1413.web.cs.unibo.it/
```

So, my root in web server is:

/home/web/ltw1413/html

Inside html folder I have:

- One folder named "annotaria
- One file .wsgi named "wsgi.wsgi"

My file .wsgi is:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/web/ltw1413/html')
from annotaria import app as application
```

Inside my folder "annotaria" I have:

- "Static" folder : inside stylesheet and js
- "Templates" folder : inside html
- "run.py" : file python where I have my application

run.py is this:

```
from pydoc import html
from annotaria import app
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
import json
import urllib2
import urlparse
import re
import string
import os
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
from rdflib import Graph, BNode, Literal, Namespace
from time import strftime
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/index.html')
def reloader():
    return render_template('index.html')


# other app.route()...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I find a solution? Where is my error?

Comment: You have an `__init__.py` in the annotaria folder?

Comment: No i don't have it! Only run.py with views inside! Is it an error?

Comment: In order to make a folder a Python package you have to add an `__init__.py`. It can be empty. After that you will be able to import from there.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of errors here...
`annotaria` is not found on path (that is why it says... well.. exactly that).

In your code you also redefine `app`: you import it from annotaria and then redefine it in `app = Flask(..`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer! i modified the path in sys.path.insert(0, '/home/web/ltw1413/html/annotaria') inside .wsgi and make comment "#from annotaria import app" in run.py but doesn't work. Same error: ImportError: No module named annotaria, referer: http://ltw1413.web.cs.unibo.it/

Answer (score 0):

Others mentioned individual errors, but it would be helpful to understand the big picture. First of all, let's assume the following structure:

```
/home/web/ltw1413/html
- wsgi.wsgi
- annotaria/
  - __init.py__
  - run.py
  - static/
  - templates
```

Like Klaus mentioned, you need `__init__.py` to tell Python that annotaria is a valid package. But then your `wsgi.wsgi` file needs to import the app from the run module:

```
from annotaria.run import app as application
```

You also need to remove this unnecessary import from `run.py`, since you instantiate a new application:

```
from annotaria import app
```

Because there is no application to import, you instantiate a new Flask application.

Finally, make sure that the app runs manually before you start deploying it.